# want to add two string elemants, how could i do that?

Tags: java

want to add the elements of two arrays. Just like,

suppose `string1=123` and `string2=456`

the result will be, `result= string1+string2=579`;

how could i do this in java. please help. I have tried but failed.

My code is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class sAdd{
double result=0;
String line1,line2;
void input(){
    System.out.println("Enter The String");
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    line1 = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter The String2");
    line2 = sc.nextLine();
}
void calc(){ 
 char[] ch=line1.toCharArray();
 char[] ch1=line2.toCharArray();
 int d=line1.length();
 System.out.println(d);
 for(int i=0;i<d;i++){
double myd1= (char)(ch[i] - '0');
System.out.println(myd1);
double myd2= (char)(ch1[i] - '0');
System.out.println(myd2);
   result = result+(myd1+myd2);  
 System.out.println(result); 
 }

}
}

 public class StrngCalc extends sAdd {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    sAdd f = new sAdd();
    f.input();
    f.calc();
}

}
```

Comment: `"" + (Integer.parseInt(s1) + Integer.parseInt(s2))`

Comment: `double myd1= (char)(ch[i] - '0');`....what?

Comment: Don't reinvent the built in String to Integer.  Use Integer.parseInt()

Comment: Since you are using Scanner, you can just read integers with Scanner.nextInt(). You shouldn't need any strings or doubles in this code.

Comment: This is Java, not C#. You can simply use scanner.nextInt() to receive integers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [`Integer.parseInt(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) which will parse the string argument as a signed decimal integer.:

```
void calc() {
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(line1) + Integer.parseInt(line2));
}
```

**Note:** This will throw an exception if one of the strings cannot be converted into an integer. You can handle this exception by using a `try-catch` block:

```
try {
    // operations
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add strings with the plus sign, it adds them together to get another string. So "123" + "456" = "123456"

You are asking to get the numeric value, so you will have to convert each string into integers and then add them together to get another integer

```
try {   
    int sum = Integer.parseInt(string1) + Integer.parseInt(string2)
catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

You have to include the statement in a try-catch block, since trying to convert something like "regulartext" into an integer will throw an exception.

Once you have gotten the sum, you can always convert it back into a string by

```
String theSum = Integer.toString(int);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Integer.parseInt](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_parseint.htm)

Your code should look like this:

```
int val1 = Integer.parseInt(str1);
int val2 = Integer.parseInt(str2);

Integer res = val1 + val2;
String resStr = res.toString();
```